# Select specific columns in a list of Sheets in R - Looping

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I have a list with 20 data.frames and I would like to filter specific columns by name (Tag, Trait1 and Trait2) from this list, after I will merge them. If the data.frame doesn't have the column, I would like to insert a column with `NA`.  So, for example I have this situation:

sheet.1

```
Tag Sex Trait1 Trait2 Trait3
1   M     23     Y      55
2   F     25     N      66
3   F     25     N      62 
4   F     26     Y      35
```

sheet.2

```
Tag  Sex Trait1 
5     M     25     
6     F     27     
7     M     25      
8     F     23
```

So I would like this:

nw.sheet.1

```
Tag Sex Trait1 Trait2 
1   M     23     Y      
2   F     25     N      
3   F     25     N       
4   F     26     Y
```

nw.sheet.2

```
Tag  Sex Trait1 Trait2
5     M     25    NA
6     F     27    NA 
7     M     25    NA  
8     F     23    NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to get the datasets in a `list`, create a `vector` of column names that we want to `select` ('nm1'), use `intersect` and `setdiff` to select the intersecting columns and columns that needs to be created as `NA` if not present in the dataset and returns the new `list` of `data.frame`s in the `list`

```
nm1 <- c("Tag", "Sex", "Trai1", "Trait2")
outlst <- lapply(lst1, function(x)  {
              nm2 <- intersect(names(x), nm1)
              nm3 <- setdiff(nm1, nm2)
              x1 <- x[nm2]
              x1[nm3] <- NA
              x1})
```

NOTE: It is not clear what the `sheets` meant.  If it is from an excel workbook, it can be loaded into a `list` with `readxl`

```
library(readxl)
file <- "file.xlsx'
lst1 <- map(1:2, ~ read_excel(file, sheet = .x))
```

Comment: Perfect @akrun =D